# How to load web page using didSelectRowAtIndexPath without leaving the app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, safari, html

I am parsing RSS feeds and loading results into a table.  When the user clicks on a story, they are taken to the web page.

At the moment I am using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:story]];
```

Trouble is that this launches Safari and closes my app.

Is there a way to open the webpage in my app so to speak?  I'd like the webpage to appear with a "Done" button that closes the web page and returns the user back to the table.

Any help (and code examples) are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIWebView in a new view controller launched via navigationController pushViewController selector, and have a toolbar item to "View in Safari" which will launch full Safari browser (and putting your app in the background/terminating).

Some example code snippets:

Assumptions: 
(1) You have a view controller entitled: WebViewController (with same .xib) file. 
(2) This view controller has a UIView which is subview of the main view;

```
@interface WebViewController: UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView *webview;
    NSString *someUrlToLoad;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someUrlToLoad;
```

In this view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.someUrlToLoad]]];
}
```

You load this controller when someone clicked on the cell in your tableview:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WebViewController *viewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.someUrlToLoad = <url for this cell>;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];

}
```

Most likely you will want to include some hook into the UIWebViewDelegate to stop/show an activity indicator in the navigation bar so the user is aware that something is happening while the page loads.

Comment: Thanks chilitechno.  I'm a bit of a newbie so your recommendation is a little confusing.  Will this switch in a new NIB, or create a subview that will overlay the table?  I only need to show one webpage (one per each row in table), so I don't need the full power of Safari.  Any chance you could post some example code?  Many thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with some example snippets. I recommend loading a new view controller with the content so that the user can hit the back button when they're done viewing the web page content.

Comment: be careful what you display INSIDE your app's webview. there are some limitations as to what you can show.  for instance: you have to show any sort of "donation" page in the safari app itself, using the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:story]];` function like you have listed.  you probably don't have to worry - but just know there are some limitations to this